# OpenCV on ARM11 architecture with Ubuntu Support

Tags: c, ubuntu, opencv, arm

I am developing a project based on OpenCV. Currently I am working on Ubuntu 10.04 system with AMD turion processor. But project need to work as an embedded system. So I am using a readymade board based on ARM11 processor with SAMSUNG S3C6410 processor. It supprot Linux 2.6.28. It also support ubuntu. So how could I port my code from the host system to my embedded system.
Thanks 
This is link for the board.
http://www.minidevs.com/

Comment: Is it all C? Do you have assembler portions? Have you tried just recompiling it on the target system, or using a cross-compiler from your development system? Does it just work? Or do you get build errors, or runtime errors?

Comment: OpenCV is all C. And I got a linux image for my development board from its vendor. And I want to know whether I could build the OpenCV on the native board likewise other libraries as in Ubuntu I have installed it using apt-get.

Comment: Actually I have to compile it to an image file for NAND flash on the board. So i think I have to cross compile the library along with the image for OS? if I am right?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to start, is to take a look at Angstrom/OpenEmbedded.

It's a framework for building OS images for various embedded platforms. You could take the precompiled-images, but I've realized that after a while it's not worth the hassle.

Just build the target image yourself (with OpenCV for the target platform, it definitely builds for S3C2440 (tested it myself a year ago or so) and for all OMAP3 platforms (BeagleBoard, EVM and the like).

Then, use OpenEmbedded to build the cross-compiler (there is a package name for that), install it on your host machine, and you should be ready to go.

If there is no support for S3C6410, just use any other ARM11 platform out there, and install the packages. It is likely your vendor-supplied OS was built using OpenEmbedded, it quickly becomes de-facto standard.

http://www.angstrom-distribution.org/

http://www.openembedded.org

Answer (score 0):

Check Linaro if the processor you are looking for is ARM. It looks promising. http://www.linaro.org/